# How to create a thread using Boost

Tags: boost-thread

I am a newbie to the boost library. Please forgive me if the answer is obvious. Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

using namespace std;

void task1(void)
{
    cout << "There" << endl;
}

int main()
{
boost::thread mythread(task1);
cout << "Hi" << endl;
}
```

When I attempt to build I receive the following:

```
/mythread1.cpp:13: undefined reference to `boost::thread::~thread()'
```

it compiles if i simply declared the thread, boost::thread mythread();

Any suggestions? I just need to know the syntax for declaring and launching this thread to complete task1().

Please, no responses off the subject. My question is simple enough. Thanks for your help. Btw, Im using Eclipse and Boost 1.42.

Comment: Your program compiles fine, its the linking that fails. The boost threading lib is not headers-only like most of boost but a library that needs to be built. Have you built it or do you have a precompiled version, and do you link to it correctly?

Comment: First, what command are you using to compile and link this program? Second, you need to fix your program so that it doesn't terminate before it finishes working. (When you return from `main`, that implicitly terminates your process.)

Comment: Thanks Rolle, David. No I haven't built it. Can you point me to a tutorial? I am using Eclipse and I've installed boost from Synaptic. From my project in Eclipse I can see the include path with all of the boost files, but not sure how to link or build or make it available to my project.

Answer (score 0):

Using Boost threads you need to link the boost thread library.
In your code you're missing the join (see threads docs)